# Retrieving data from vectors and unordered_sets

Tags: c++, vector, unordered-set

I've started to put data into `vector`s and `unordered_set`s. I've worked out fairly easily how to put the data in, and I know how to get the data out if I need to unload all the data, for example:

```
for (auto i : vehicles)
    MakeSpawnInfoVehicle(i.AddedInformation);
```

However, I've reached a point where I want just one element of information from either the `unordered_set`s or `vector`s such as what ever the 10th entry is in the `vector` or the `unordered_set`.

If someone could provide a basic example of both, I'm sure I'll understand it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In situations like this, you can consult a [good reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/).

`std::vector` provides `operator[]` with constant-time performance:

```
auto tenth_element = vehicle_vector[9];
```

`std::unordered_set` is optimised for element-based lookup (that is, testing whether an element is present or not). It is rare you would need the 10th element (especially since the set is, by definition, *unordered*), but if you do, you take an iterator, increment it and dereference it:

```
auto tenth_element = *std::next(vehicle_set.begin(), 9);
```

---

In general, you access the elements of a container either through the container's member functions (such as the vector's `operator []` above), or through an *iterator.*

An iterator is a generalisation of a pointer - it's *some unspecified type* which points to an element in the container. You can then work with iterators using their member functions like `operator ++` or free functions like `std::next()`. Random-access iterators also support `[]`. To get the element to which the iterator "points," dereference the iterator like `*it` or `it->whatever`.

You obtain an iterator to the beginning of the container using `begin()` and an iterator to one past the last element using `end()`. Containers can also provide other member functions to get an iterator to an element - such as `vehicle_set.find(aVehicle)`, which returns an iterator to `aVehicle` if it's present in the set, or the `end()` iterator if it's not.

Which member functions a container offers depends on which container it is and in particular how efficient the operations are. `std::vector` doesn't proivde `find()`, because it would be no better than `std::find()` - there is no structure in `std::vector` for fast lookup. `std::unordered_set` does provide `find()`, but doesn't have `operator []`, because its iterators are not random-access: accessing the *n*th element of an unordered set requires time proportional to *n.*